# Incrementing state in useEffect sometimes result in a wrong state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a simple chat app with React and socketio, here is the `useEffect` for receiving messages:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("new-message", () => {
    setMessagesCount(messagesCount + 1) //THIS DOESNT WORK
  })
}, [])
```

The problem is that when I increment the `messagesCount` state, it doesn't increment and sometimes it decrements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use callback form of setState, i.e. line #7 becomes

```js
setMessage(messages => [...messages, data])
```

Edit: and to count the messages, it should be

```js
setMessagesCount(messagesCount => messagesCount+1);
```

**Reason:**

This is because `messages` is a useEffect dependency and since that hook is set once component mounts and doesn't change for subsequent re-renders, the reference to `messages` also doesn't change for the hook. The callback form of setState allows us to use latest value of messages without adding `messages` to that useEffect's dependencies.

Comment: as an improvement and based on the state, it should be `setMessagesCount(prevMessageCount => prevMessageCount++)`